# What is differential probability?

Tags: probability, differential-geometry, density-function, differential

I am trying to understand the following statement (taken from a context related to volumetric image rendering):

> Density denotes the differential probability that a ray interacts with the volumetric “medium” of the scene at a particular point

What does differential probability mean? (especially that density in this context is defined at any point in 3D space)

Comment: Do you know what a probability density function is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a distribution (here in $3$D space) has a density $f(x,y,z)$, that means that for (almost) any volume in that space $V$, you can assign a probability to it by integrating the density (here "density" means probability per unit volume, very similar to, say, the concentration of salt in a solution):

$$P(V) = \int_V f(x,y,z)dV$$

From the above, you can see why it's also a "differential probability" (although I've never heard that term).

Comment: I would have thought that _differential_ should be something like infinitesimal *difference*, i.e. `dP` in the case of differential probability. But what confuses me is the fact that it is said to be defined at any 3D point, while I would have thought that a difference at a point can only be defined along a certain direction around that point.

Comment: @Beginner it does — $f(x,y,z)dV = dP$

Comment: @Beginner you don’t need a direction — the volume integral can be expressed as a triple integral but that will depend on the geometry of what you are integrating over.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarifications!